# How to put a button next to a RadioListTile ? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to put an **information button** that works just like an `AlertDialog()` but I'm having problems to put it next to the checkbox text since they're organized inside a `Column()` and I cannot just put a `Row()` inside of it.

[image]

**Here is the code of the checkboxes:**

```
Column (
// ...
RadioListTile(
                          title: Text('Pelagens de camundongos',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
                          value: 1,
                          groupValue: id,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              predominant = 'recessiva_aa';
                              id = 1;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                        RadioListTile(
                          title: Text('Pelagem em cães labradores',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
                          value: 2,
                          groupValue: id,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              predominant = 'recessiva_ee';
                              id = 2;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the title of your `RadioListTile` instead of putting a text widget you can put a row and inside of that row have `Text` and an `IconButton` that will pop up your alert dialog when pressed like this

```
 Column(
  children: [
    RadioListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Pelagens de camundongos',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.info_outline,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
            // code to pop up alert dialog
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      value: 1,
      groupValue: id,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          predominant = 'recessiva_aa';
          id = 1;
        });
      },
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 5.0,
    ),
    RadioListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Pelagem em cães labradores',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.info_outline,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
            // code to pop up alert dialog
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      value: 2,
      groupValue: id,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          predominant = 'recessiva_ee';
          id = 2;
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```